# Get Screenshot URLs crawled by Shodan

Tags: shodan

When shodan crawls an IP, it takes a screenshot based on some technique(?)
Nevertheless, most of screenshots that shodan takes are from IP Cameras.

**Is there any way to access the URLs the crawler found the image on?**

E.g. Crawler found `"rtsp://blargh.com/1/stream"` and took a screenshot of that stream. Can I somehow access this exact URL? In the API response there is seems to be no information about this other than the `data` key, which purpose I havent found out yet.

Comment: Maybe @achillean can help?

Comment: Are you asking how to access data over the `rtsp` protocol?

Comment: @forest no, but I think my question has already been answered by achillean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to get the URL of the image as Shodan doesn't store that information. Not all images are collected from services that have URLs (ex. RDP). Note that the actual screenshot image is stored in the `data` property. Here's a sample screenshot JSON object stored in the `opts.screenshot` property on the banner:

```
{
    "data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAJwAnAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQO...",
    "hash": 29478602,
    "labels": ["windows", "login", "desktop"],
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "text": "am Windows Server 2012R2"
}
```

The `data` property is a base64-encoded string of the image. The `hash` is a numeric hash of the `data` property (useful for finding duplicate images). The `labels` are high-level classifications of the image based on machine learning. The `mime` is the MIME-type of the image (we mostly use JPEG at the moment but it could change). And `text` is the text in the image that was extracted using OCR.

And most images are actually of remote desktops. Around 75% of images on Shodan at the moment are of remote desktops. Webcams on HTTP are a comparatively small at ~8% and RTSP takes most of the remainder. We also look at X11 and VNC but those are a tiny fraction of the images.